# Java string delimit regex with word, spaces and special characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split, java-8

I have two strings:

```
String one = "D -> B: 24"; // I am expecting array to have ['D','B','24']
String two = "route D -> C"; // expecting array to have ['D','C']
```

My regex is:

```
String myarray[] = input.split("\\s*(->|:|\\s)\\s*");
```

I am unit testing the result, for String one it is working fine and returning me exactly 3 in the array but for second String two it returns an empty space in the array as well.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks

---

The String two returns 3 elements in the array, [ ,'D','C']

Comment: What is the return value for string two?  Which space is it capturing?

Comment: `[A-Z\\d]+` .........

Comment: @cxw I edited my question. Please look.

Comment: @AvinashRaj what about '->' and ':' ?

Comment: what I get on my side is [route, D, C] for two

Comment: If basically, you want capitalized letters and numbers, split using the following regex : `[^A-Z\d]+` (don't forget to escape the characters if needed)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto strange, as I am getting blank as first element.

Comment: Why are you expecting the word "route" to disappear? Evidently it did on your side, but I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @johnnyaug because I do not want to take that into the calculation of my process ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want capitals and numbers - i.e. `[A-Z0-9]+`. The simplest approach is to remove all leading and trailing non-matching chars - i.e. `[^A-Z0-9]+`, then split on non-matching chars, like this:

```
String myarray[] = input.replaceAll("^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$", "").split("[^A-Z0-9]+");
```

---

BTW your posted code would produce `[route, D, C]`, not `[D, C]`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
String myarray[] = two.split("\\s*(->|:)\\s*");
```

You will have to write separate logic to handle non-matching characters like "route" in this case.